# F# Deedle's csv file load time

Tags: f#, type-providers, f#-interactive, deedle

I have been using the CSV provider to load files of about 300k to 1M rows (50~120megs). It works very well and is very fast. It can load most files in under a second. 
Here is the output from 64-bit FSI on windows loading a file of about 400k rows and 25 fields.

```
#time
let Csv2 = CsvFile.Parse(testfile)
let parsedRows = Csv2.Rows |> Seq.toArray
#time

--> Timing now on

Real: 00:00:00.056, CPU: 00:00:00.093, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
```

But when I load the same file into Deedle

```
#time
let dCsv = Frame.ReadCsv(testfile)
#time;;

--> Timing now on

Real: 00:01:39.197, CPU: 00:01:41.119, GC gen0: 6324, gen1: 417, gen2: 13
```

It takes over 1m 40s. I know some extra time is necessary as Deedle is doing much more than the static csv parser above, but over 1m 40s  secs seems high. Can I somehow shorten it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the `Frame.ReadCsv` function attempts to infer the type of the columns by looking at the contents. I think this might be adding most of the overhead here. You can try specifying `inferTypes=false` to disable this completely (then it'll load the data as strings) or you can use `inferRows=10` to infer the types from the first few rows. This should work well enough and be faster:

```
let df = Frame.ReadCsv(testfile, inferRows=10)
```

Maybe we should make something this the default option. If this does not fix the problem, please submit a GitHub issue and we'll look into that!

Comment: Thanks. adding `inferRows=10` reduced it to -> 
`Real: 00:00:11.075, CPU: 00:00:11.074, GC gen0: 611, gen1: 2`

Comment: I tried this at various settings of `inferRows=x`. There was virtually no difference between `inferRows=10` and `inferRows=100`, so you could probably default this to the first 100 rows.